# Scrapy - Getting the data from filterbox(Python)

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I got a problem with Scrapy. I need to get the all the city names from the red circled part in the image which I linked below. But with my code I can't return anything. I tried many alternatives yet no success. How can I solve this problem and get these city names ? The link to image and source code is below.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider
#from city_crawl.items import CityCrawlItem


class details(CrawlSpider):
    name = "city_crawling"  
        start_urls = ['https://www.booking.com/searchresults.tr.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaOQBiAEBmAEowgEKd2luZG93cyAxMMgBDNgBAegBAfgBC5ICAXmoAgM&sid=cfc09bd0db4d07c7b55902c6d0ae81a5&track_lsso=1&sb=1&src=index&src_elem=sb&error_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Findex.tr.html%3Flabel%3Dgen173nr-1FCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaOQBiAEBmAEowgEKd2luZG93cyAxMMgBDNgBAegBAfgBC5ICAXmoAgM%3Bsid%3Dcfc09bd0db4d07c7b55902c6d0ae81a5%3Bsb_price_type%3Dtotal%26%3B&ss=isve%C3%A7&checkin_monthday=&checkin_month=&checkin_year=&checkout_monthday=&checkout_month=&checkout_year=&room1=A%2CA&no_rooms=1&group_adults=2&group_children=0']


def parse(self, response):
    for content in response.xpath('//a[contains(@data-name, "uf")]'):
        yield {
            'text': content.css('span.filter_label::text').extract()
        }
```

[Image of the source which i need to parse the data. The red circled part in the left is what i need to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djdzP.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `for` loop is to select the `<a>` element with `class` contain "`uf`", it will return nothing. Should select the element with `data-name` contain "`uf`", you can change your code like this:

```
for content in response.xpath('//a[contains(@data-name, "uf")]'):
    yield {
        'text': content.css('span.filter_label::text').extract()
    }
```

**Update:**

I have tested your url links, you are right, it will return nothing. The root cause is that scrapy redirect three times, and finally went to wrong page, it scrawl in the wrong page "`https://www.booking.com/country/se.tr.html`", and this page is not same as the one showing in your image. the log is below:

```
2017-04-30 15:18:47 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.bookin
g.com/searchresults.tr.html?ss=isve%25C3%25A7> from <GET https://www.booking.com
/searchresults.tr.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaOQBiAEBmAEowgEK
d2luZG93cyAxMMgBDNgBAegBAfgBC5ICAXmoAgM&sid=cfc09bd0db4d07c7b55902c6d0ae81a5&tra
ck_lsso=1&sb=1&src=index&src_elem=sb&error_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Fi
ndex.tr.html%3Flabel%3Dgen173nr-1FCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaOQBiAEBmAEowgEKd2luZG
93cyAxMMgBDNgBAegBAfgBC5ICAXmoAgM%3Bsid%3Dcfc09bd0db4d07c7b55902c6d0ae81a5%3Bsb_
price_type%3Dtotal%26%3B&ss=isve%C3%A7&checkin_monthday=&checkin_month=&checkin_
year=&checkout_monthday=&checkout_month=&checkout_year=&room1=A%2CA&no_rooms=1&g
roup_adults=2&group_children=0>
2017-04-30 15:18:48 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET https://www.bookin
g.com/searchresults.tr.html?ss=isve%C3%A7> from <GET https://www.booking.com/sea
rchresults.tr.html?ss=isve%25C3%25A7>
2017-04-30 15:18:48 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://www.bookin
g.com/country/se.tr.html> from <GET https://www.booking.com/searchresults.tr.htm
l?ss=isve%C3%A7>
2017-04-30 15:18:49 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.booking.com/c
ountry/se.tr.html> (referer: None)
2017-04-30 15:18:49 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

**Solution:**

You could try to save the html file in your local PC like I did, named with "Booking.html", and then change your code to:

```
import scrapy

class CitiesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "city_crawling"
    start_urls = [
        'file:///F:/algorithm%20study/python/StackOverFlow/Booking.html', # put the saved html file directory here
#        'https://www.booking.com/searchresults.tr.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaOQBiAEBmAEowgEKd2luZG93cyAxMMgBDNgBAegBAfgBC5ICAXmoAgM&sid=cfc09bd0db4d07c7b55902c6d0ae81a5&track_lsso=1&sb=1&src=index&src_elem=sb&error_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.booking.com%2Findex.tr.html%3Flabel%3Dgen173nr-1FCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaOQBiAEBmAEowgEKd2luZG93cyAxMMgBDNgBAegBAfgBC5ICAXmoAgM%3Bsid%3Dcfc09bd0db4d07c7b55902c6d0ae81a5%3Bsb_price_type%3Dtotal%26%3B&ss=isve%C3%A7&checkin_monthday=&checkin_month=&checkin_year=&checkout_monthday=&checkout_month=&checkout_year=&room1=A%2CA&no_rooms=1&group_adults=2&group_children=0',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        #self.logger.info('A response from %s just arrived!', response.url)
        for content in response.xpath('//a[contains(@data-name, "uf")]'):
            #self.logger.info('TEST %s TEST', content.css('span.filter_label::text').extract()) 
            yield {
                'text': content.css('span.filter_label::text').extract()
            }
```

Run the scrawl command in your scrapy project : `scrapy crawl city_crawling`, it will give you start to scrawl the information you want, check below logs and output:

```
2017-04-30 15:33:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET file:///F:/algorithm%20st
udy/python/StackOverFlow/Booking.html> (referer: None)
2017-04-30 15:33:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 file:///F:/algorithm%20stu
dy/python/StackOverFlow/Booking.html>
{'text': [u'\nStockholm\n']}
2017-04-30 15:33:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 file:///F:/algorithm%20stu
dy/python/StackOverFlow/Booking.html>
{'text': [u'\nG\xf6teborg\n']}
2017-04-30 15:33:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 file:///F:/algorithm%20stu
dy/python/StackOverFlow/Booking.html>
{'text': [u'\nVisby\n']}
2017-04-30 15:33:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 file:///F:/algorithm%20stu
dy/python/StackOverFlow/Booking.html>
{'text': [u'\nFalkenberg\n']}
2017-04-30 15:33:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 file:///F:/algorithm%20stu
dy/python/StackOverFlow/Booking.html>
{'text': [u'\nMalm\xf6\n']}
2017-04-30 15:33:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 file:///F:/algorithm%20stu
dy/python/StackOverFlow/Booking.html>
{'text': [u'\nLysekil\n']}
2017-04-30 15:33:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 file:///F:/algorithm%20stu
dy/python/StackOverFlow/Booking.html>
{'text': [u'\nSimrishamn\n']}
2017-04-30 15:33:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 file:///F:/algorithm%20stu
dy/python/StackOverFlow/Booking.html>
{'text': [u'\nLund\n']}
2017-04-30 15:33:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 file:///F:/algorithm%20stu
dy/python/StackOverFlow/Booking.html>
{'text': [u'\nK\xf6pingsvik\n']}
2017-04-30 15:33:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 file:///F:/algorithm%20stu
dy/python/StackOverFlow/Booking.html>
{'text': [u'\nBorgholm\n']}
2017-04-30 15:33:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 file:///F:/algorithm%20stu
dy/python/StackOverFlow/Booking.html>
{'text': [u'\nJ\xf6nk\xf6ping\n']}
2017-04-30 15:33:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 file:///F:/algorithm%20stu
dy/python/StackOverFlow/Booking.html>
{'text': [u'\nUppsala\n']}
2017-04-30 15:33:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 file:///F:/algorithm%20stu
dy/python/StackOverFlow/Booking.html>
{'text': [u'\nF\xe4rjestaden\n']}
2017-04-30 15:33:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 file:///F:/algorithm%20stu
dy/python/StackOverFlow/Booking.html>
{'text': [u'\nHelsingborg\n']}
2017-04-30 15:33:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 file:///F:/algorithm%20stu
dy/python/StackOverFlow/Booking.html>
{'text': [u'\nRonneby\n']}
2017-04-30 15:33:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 file:///F:/algorithm%20stu
dy/python/StackOverFlow/Booking.html>
{'text': [u'\nYstad\n']}
2017-04-30 15:33:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 file:///F:/algorithm%20stu
dy/python/StackOverFlow/Booking.html>
{'text': [u'\nHalmstad\n']}
2017-04-30 15:33:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 file:///F:/algorithm%20stu
dy/python/StackOverFlow/Booking.html>
{'text': [u'\nKivik\n']}
2017-04-30 15:33:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 file:///F:/algorithm%20stu
dy/python/StackOverFlow/Booking.html>
{'text': [u'\nBorrby\n']}
2017-04-30 15:33:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 file:///F:/algorithm%20stu
dy/python/StackOverFlow/Booking.html>
{'text': [u'\nFj\xe4llbacka\n']}
2017-04-30 15:33:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 file:///F:/algorithm%20stu
dy/python/StackOverFlow/Booking.html>
{'text': [u'\nKarlskrona\n']}
2017-04-30 15:33:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 file:///F:/algorithm%20stu
dy/python/StackOverFlow/Booking.html>
{'text': [u'\nGr\xe4nna\n']}
2017-04-30 15:33:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 file:///F:/algorithm%20stu
dy/python/StackOverFlow/Booking.html>
{'text': [u'\nL\xf6ttorp\n']}
2017-04-30 15:33:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 file:///F:/algorithm%20stu
dy/python/StackOverFlow/Booking.html>
{'text': [u'\nNorrk\xf6ping\n']}
2017-04-30 15:33:31 [scrapy] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 file:///F:/algorithm%20stu
dy/python/StackOverFlow/Booking.html>
{'text': [u'\n\xd6rebro\n']}
2017-04-30 15:33:31 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
```

Comment: Sadly it is still returning nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
`
def parse(self, response):
    for content in response.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "uf")]'):
        yield {

             'text':content.css('span.filter_label::text').extract(),
            }
```

`
U need to keep  **comma** at the end of

"'text':content.css('span.filter_label::text').extract()"

Comment: Sadly it is still returning nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
def parse(self, response):
    for content in response.css('a[data-name=uf)]'):
        yield {
            'text': content.css('span.filter_label::text').extract(),
        }
```

Check it  now 
it works